# What should I do with emails using charset ansi_x3.110-1983?

Tags: character-encoding, ascii

My application is parsing incoming emails. I try to parse them as best as possible but every now and then I get one with puzzling content. This time is an email that looks to be in ASCII but the specified charset is: `ansi_x3.110-1983`.

My application handles it correctly by defaulting to ASCII, but it throws a warning which I'd like to stop receiving, so my question is: what is ansi_x3.110-1983 and what should I do with it?

Comment: Hi, did assuming "ansi_x3.110-1983" being equivalent to ASCII work for you? Or did you consider it to be ISO-8859-1 like the answer below? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page on the IANA's site](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xml), `ANSI_X3.110-1983` is also known as:

- `iso-ir-99`
- `CSA_T500-1983`
- `NAPLPS`
- `csISO99NAPLPS`

Of those, only the name [NAPLPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAPLPS) seems interesting or informative.  If you can, consider getting in touch with the people sending those mails.  If they're *really* using **Prodigy** in this day and age, I'd be amazed.

The IANA site also has a pointer to [RFC 1345](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1345), which contains a description of the bytes and the characters that they map to.  Compared to ISO-8859-1, the control characters are the same, as are most of the punctuation, all of the numbers and letters, and most of the remaining characters in the first 7 bits.

You could possibly use the guide in the RFC to write a tool to map the characters over, if someone hasn't written a tool for it already.  To be honest, it may be easier to simply ignore the whines about the weird character set given that the character mapping is close enough to what is expected anyway...